# Is there a way to do a stratified train/test split without shuffling the data?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, split, data-science, train-test-split

I'm using time sensitive data and would like to maintain the order of the data but stratifying the data since I've got multiple labels. I haven't found any libraries that allow this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Juanro could you provide with an example what are you trying to do as it might help to understand the problem in a better way
Thanks:

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [train_test_split documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).

You can do somthing like this:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=0, 
                                                    stratify=y)
```

The `stratify = y` will give a stratified split with same proportions of class labels as the input dataset.